# What kind of connector is this? From my old mobile wifi router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, connector, wireless-card

I found my old mobile router, and the WiFi reach is too short, so I plan on adding an external antenna for my travels.

I was wondering what kind of connection this was, and I have a spare PCIE wifi card I can cannibalise on, and a U.FL to RP-SMA connector that I bought from Aliexpress.

[image: Photography of the circuit board]

Can anyone tell me what kind of connector it is? The black and gold ones?

Answer (score 0):

Those are muRata SWG series or similar. Unlike Hirose u.fl, this kind of muRata connector is only designed to connect to a temporary RF probe in a lab setting. It's not physically designed to hold onto an antenna lead tightly.

Answer (score -1):

they are GSM or 3G or 4G Signal Transceivers (transmitter cum receiver)

Every mobile phones,3G/4G router ,3G/4G  dongle have that transceivers.
 if you can not get enough signal strenth from your carrier (the one whose sim card your using) then you can connect external antena to it.

this:
[image: External Antena..]

adding external antena will not have any effect on wifi signal strenth though..

Comment: Please clarify and add a little more context to this answer to convey what you are suggesting exactly. You know, consider adding some reference to this answer supporting what you state. Otherwise, read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.